# Gini Coefficient - Variable Importance Measure

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, nonlinear-regression, importance, gini

There is a whitepaper titled "[Entropy-based Measures of Weight of Evidence and Information Value for Variable Reduction and Segmentation for Continuous Dependent Variables](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/3242-2015.pdf)" for selecting important variables in a linear regression model.

It explains that the [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) can be used to check linearity in the model. And we can also rank variable based on their GINI coefficient. A higher Gini coefficient suggests a higher potential for the variable to be useful in a linear regression. If a numeric variable is high on IV Rank but low on Gini coefficient, it usually suggests a lack of linearity.

My Question: Is it the Gini coefficient derived from decision tree? Or it is related to area under curve $\left(\text{AUC}\right) – \left(\text{Gini} = 2\times \text{AUC} - 1\right)$? What is the exact calculation of this Gini coefficient and how it can be used to check linearity? I googled a lot. What I got is it is used in economics theory to check inequality.

Comment: There should be better answers, but as an interim: watch out. Corrado Gini was very inventive and industrious and his name has been attached in different fields to various quite different measures. Never believe the name; always look at the definition.

Comment: In this case, it is related to AUC or Tree?

Comment: Either; that's the point.

Comment: Wow. what an explanation!

Comment: I've glanced at the paper you cite. It just says Gini coefficient and only by looking at the code can you work out what he's doing. This is the problem!